# Serve static content on a per servlet basis

Tags: java, jetty, javax.ws.rs

I'm making an application which loads modules dynamically based on configuration files. Each module has its own servlet and its own path.

It works, but so far it's only serving content I annotate with `@Path` in my classes (rest services), thanks to the `ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES` property:

Context:

```
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler( ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS );
    context.setContextPath( "/" );
```

Each module/servlet is initialized like this:

```
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet( org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/" );
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder( 0 );
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter( ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "com.my.packages.rest.server.root" );
```

This gives me a url path per module - great.

But I also have some static html in the resource/modulename folder of each module, which I don't know how to serve...

With a DefaultServlet, I can do it like this:

```
    DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
    ServletHolder staticAppServlet = new ServletHolder( "default", defaultServlet );
    staticAppServlet.setInitParameter( "resourceBase", "./src/main/resources/modulename/" );
    context.addServlet( staticAppServlet, "/path" );
```

But I don't know how to do it with a jetty `ServletHolder`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reuse the name "default", make a new name for each module.

It is also important that you use a fully qualified path to your Resource Base, either as a full file system path, or as an absolute URL.

Here's an example from the [embedded-jetty-cookbook](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook) example called [`DefaultServletMultipleBases.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/DefaultServletMultipleBases.java)

```java
// add special pathspec of "/alt/" content mapped to the altPath
ServletHolder holderAlt = new ServletHolder("static-alt", DefaultServlet.class);
holderAlt.setInitParameter("resourceBase",altPath.toUri().toASCIIString());
holderAlt.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
holderAlt.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly","true");
context.addServlet(holderAlt,"/alt/*");
```

Comment: you mean you can have more than one defaultservlet?

Comment: Sure, its just a Servlet.  Only the one named "default" is special (for error handling)

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it as soon as possible.